# oracle forms get data that are both in table and multi row block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a table that looks like this

```
+-------+
|stud_id|
+-------+
|10     |
|13     |
|12     |
|11     |
|15     |
+-------+
```

and a multi row block like this

[image]

what I wanted is that for example after clicking the button I have values 13,12,14 in my multi row block, a message will appear that contains the stud_id that is both in my table and multi row block block which are the numbers **13 and 12** only and not 14 because it is not included in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tabular form (the one that contains several rows) is based on some table, I presume. Let's call it `FORM_TBL`. Also, suppose that table name which contains data you posted is called `STUD_TBL`.

A simple option is to **post** data entered into the form (which means that they'll end up in the table, but won't be committed and nobody but you will see those rows) and then - using the `INTERSECT` set operator - find common values. That would be the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger:

```
declare
  retval varchar2(200);
begin
  post; 

  select listagg(stud_id, ',') within group (order by stud_id) 
  into retval
  from (select stud_id from stud_tbl
        intersect
        select s_id from form_tbl
      );

  message('Common values: ' || retval);
end;
```

If your Forms version doesn't support `LISTAGG`, you can do it in a loop:

```
declare
  retval varchar2(200);
begin
  post; 

  for cur_r in (select stud_id from stud_tbl
                intersect
                select s_id from form_tbl
               )
  loop
    retval := retval ||', '|| cur_r.stud_id;
  end loop;
  message('Common values: ' || retval);
end;
```

Otherwise, if `POST` doesn't satisfy your needs, you'll have to loop through all rows in a form and check whether they exist in the `STUD_TBL` or not.

Comment: Sir, I think POST wont satisfy my needs because I am using some auto generated values in some other columns in my table. I think I need tot use that loop through all rows then compare. Please help me :(

Comment: I'd suggest you not to *think* but to **try** it. It is the way to do that.